# Exception Driven Programming for PHP?

Tags: testing, exception

I saw Jeff Atwood's post on his blog about [Exception Driven Programming](https://blog.codinghorror.com/exception-driven-development/) and I was curious if there is anything like [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/archive/p/elmah/) for PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/) is providing monitoring of PHP applications. 
The things it can monitor includes:

- application response time
- failed user requests
- application accesibility
- generated errors

This is probably the closest you can get to your needs.